# a way to execute android app functions with gtest

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator, googletest

I am working with visual studio and want to make tests go through all functions of my Android app with different options.

I simply don't want do it manually by hand to see if all functions work. I'd like to do this just with the emulator with a 5 second delay between each action.

Is there a way I could do it with gtest?